# Unable to align the Divider between Grid items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to have `Divider` between `Grid` item.

The output should be like this:-

> Col 1 |  Col 2  | Col 3

Though in my code I'm unable to see the `Divider` and also the items are aligned in vertical fashion.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Grid, Divider } from "@material-ui/core";
export default function App() {
  const tempArray = ['Col 1', 'Col 2', 'Col 3'];
  return(
    <Grid container align='center' direction='column'>
      {tempArray.map((title)=>{
        return(
          <Grid container direction='row'>
            <Grid item xs>
              <strong>{title}</strong>
            </Grid>
            <Divider orientation='vertical' flexItem></Divider>
          </Grid>
        );
        }
      )}

    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Also, I'm not sure how I can skip the Divider for the last item. 
Here's the code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-curran-ggs27?file=/src/App.js:0-529).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Grid`s inside the `Grid` container need to have the `xs` prop set to `true` to allow it to share the available space ([docs](https://mui.com/components/grid/#auto-layout)). Otherwise it will try to occupy the whole viewport width which is the default behavior.

> I'm not sure how I can skip the Divider for the last item.

You can render the `Divider` conditionally based on the current index:

```
{i !== tempArray.length - 1 && (
  <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem></Divider>
)}
```

Full working code:

```
<Grid container align="center">
  {tempArray.map((title, i) => {
    return (
      <Grid key={title} item container xs /* <------------------ add this */>
        <Grid item xs>
          <strong>{title}</strong>
        </Grid>
        {i !== tempArray.length - 1 && (
          <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem></Divider>
        )}
      </Grid>
    );
  })}
</Grid>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to align it horizontally.

**index.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Grid, Divider } from "@material-ui/core";
export default function App() {
  const tempArray = ["Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"];
  return (
    <Grid container align="center" direction="column">
      <Grid container direction="row">
        {tempArray.map((title, index) => {
          return (
            <Grid item xs key={index}>
              <strong>{title}</strong>
              <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem></Divider>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```